# pygame android preplash image stays for ever

Tags: android, pygame

I am facing strange problem for my small game written in python
I am pushing this to andorid using this doc http://pygame.renpy.org/index.html

But my android-presplash.jpg stays for ever in the screen.Eventhough I am blitting 
different Introduction screen.
(http://pygame.renpy.org/android-advanced.html)

I tried with my all virtual Devices and my LG mobile with 2.3 android.

Please suggest some solution to reslove this.
Below is part of my code:

```
import pygame

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.window = pygame.display.set_mode((1300,500))

    def checkRectCollidePoint(self,rect,pos,x):
        NewRect=pygame.Rect(rect.left+x[0], rect.top+x[1], rect.width, rect.height)
        if NewRect.collidepoint(pos):
            return True

    def loadingScreen(self):
        loadingScreenSprite=pygame.image.load('Intro.jpg').convert_alpha()  
        loadingScreenSprite = loadingScreenSprite.convert_alpha() 

        myfont = pygame.font.Font("comic.ttf", 40)
        ExitText  = myfont.render("Exit    :", 1,[0,0,128])

        dirty=[]
        dirty.append(self.window.blit(loadingScreenSprite,(0,0)))
        dirty.append(self.window.blit(ExitText, [120,300]))
        pygame.display.update(dirty)

        needgoodVarRunning=True
        while needgoodVarRunning:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    if self.checkRectCollidePoint(ExitText.get_rect(),pos,[120,300]):
                        needgoodVarRunning=False
def main():
    game = Game() 
    game.loadingScreen()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Why are you only updating dirty?  You should only use the ability of pygame.display.update to have arguments if you are not wanting to update everything that was blitted since you last updated, which I don't see any of. Also, you should be clearing the screen each blit with window.fill((255, 255, 255)), unless I'm missing something.  I don't know if this will help your problem, but I thought I'd let you know.

Comment: @PygameNerd thanks for suggestion. I tried and it did't work for me.:( any other things to try.

Comment: Also you are not updating your screen in your main game loop.

Comment: Something you might want to try is removing the `self.` in the line `dirty.append(self.window.blit(loadingScreenSprite,(0,0)))` and the one below it.

Comment: Remove `pygame.init()`

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely a problem with a driver. [`pygame.init()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.init) initializes all pygame modules. This may take some time on some systems. If you don't need all pygame modules, just leave it out. For the display and event handling it is not necessary to call `pygame.init()` at all. If you need other modules, you can initialize them separately (e.g. `pygame.font.init()`, `pygame.mixer.init()`).

See [`pygame.init()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html)

> Initialize all imported pygame modules. No exceptions will be raised if a module fails, but the total number if successful and failed inits will be returned as a tuple. You can always initialize individual modules manually, but `pygame.init()` initialize all imported pygame modules is a convenient way to get everything started. The `init()` functions for individual modules will raise exceptions when they fail.
>
> **You may want to initialize the different modules separately to speed up your program or to not use modules your game does not require.**